# Parsing JSON in React

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing

I have this code:

```
<div>
     <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.dat, null, 2) }</pre>
</div>
```

And this is the JSON object result:

```
{
  "labels": [
    "Si",
    "No"
  ],
  "datasets": [
    {
      "data": [
        10,
        6
      ],
      "backgroundColor": [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56",
        "#F44336",
        "#9C27B0",
        "#673AB7",
        "#3F51B5",
        "#2196F3",
        "#00BCD4",
        "#009688",
        "#4CAF50",
        "#8BC34A",
        "#CDDC39",
        "#FFEB3B",
        "#FFC107",
        "#FF9800",
        "#FF5722",
        "#795548",
        "#9E9E9E",
        "#607D8B",
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56",
        "#F44336",
        "#9C27B0",
        "#673AB7",
        "#3F51B5",
        "#2196F3",
        "#00BCD4",
        "#009688",
        "#4CAF50",
        "#8BC34A",
        "#CDDC39",
        "#FFEB3B",
        "#FFC107",
        "#FF9800",
        "#FF5722",
        "#795548",
        "#9E9E9E",
        "#607D8B"
      ],
      "hoverBackgroundColor": [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56",
        "#F44336",
        "#9C27B0",
        "#673AB7",
        "#3F51B5",
        "#2196F3",
        "#00BCD4",
        "#009688",
        "#4CAF50",
        "#8BC34A",
        "#CDDC39",
        "#FFEB3B",
        "#FFC107",
        "#FF9800",
        "#FF5722",
        "#795548",
        "#9E9E9E",
        "#607D8B",
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56",
        "#F44336",
        "#9C27B0",
        "#673AB7",
        "#3F51B5",
        "#2196F3",
        "#00BCD4",
        "#009688",
        "#4CAF50",
        "#8BC34A",
        "#CDDC39",
        "#FFEB3B",
        "#FFC107",
        "#FF9800",
        "#FF5722",
        "#795548",
        "#9E9E9E",
        "#607D8B"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to print only "labels" and "data" to have (in a div) something like, you know:

Si: 10
No: 6

But even when I try to use something like this:

```
                <div>
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.dat.labels, null, 2) }</pre>
                </div>
```

and error comes up:

×
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'labels' of null**

How should I parse this? Or any suggestion to have the result I am looking for?

**Updates:**

this is the function where I am having the JSON Object (anyways is a personal API created within Java):

```
   componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get(`${Constants.ROUTE_WEB_SERVICES}${Constants.GET_DATA_GRAPHICS_QUESTION}${this.props.question.id}`)
        .then(res => {         

            this.setState({
                dat :res.data
            })
        });
    }
```

Comment: Based on the code and structure you've shown, this should work, so there must be something else to it. It could be that you need to ensure `ths.state.dat` exists if you're waiting for an asynchronous response to show up for the initial render, something like `{this.state.dat ? (key into .labels) : (render something else until response arrives)}`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do your work in JS, before you return anything, and then template that result in. The best termplates don't have any logic in them (although you usually end up with a few `map()` operations anyway), you already did all of that and have variables declared that you can just `{ reference }`. Now when things don't work, it's a plain JS problem, not "React".

Comment: Is your JSON coming from an API call? Then initially `state.dat` could be undefined.

Comment: Hey, I am having the JSON Object with a call to an API, with AXIOS and an async function. I am attaching the code now

Comment: Add catch block to see what errors do you get ```.catch(err => console.log(err))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your component initially renders, it does't have data in state, hence the error. You need to enable it to render without erros.

You can set empty array as labels in initial state or use optional chaining:

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state?.dat?.labels, null, 2) }
```

Or something like

```
<pre>{this.state.dat && JSON.stringify(this.state.dat.labels, null, 2)}
```

Or older ECMA versions.

Comment: This is awsome and works, specially the second one for me. But if I want to show the datasets.data how would I do? Its not working JSON.stringify(this.state.dat.datasets.data, null, 2).

Comment: @FeberCastellon something like `this.state.dat.datasets[0].data`